# Rails 3 - Image Attachments and Performance

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, performance, paperclip, carrierwave

I am looking for the most performant way to attach 4 images and looking for suggestions.  I feel my options are as follows.  My guess that option 1 is the fastest performance wise, and option 3 is the most expensive but flexible and extensible.  I'm only going to ever allow 4 images and would be ok with creating a object_photo and object2_photo model if need be to make sure that I only have the photos I need for the object I need them for.  I'm going to have TONS of requests and images over time. Already up to 2000 and get about 11,000 hits a month right now.

Option 1)

```
class Object < ActiveRecord::Base
   # add 4 image field on the object
end
```

Option 2)

```
class Object < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :photos, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :object
end
```

Option 3)

```
class Object < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :photos, :as => :attachable, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :attachable, :polymorphic => true
   belongs_to :object
end
```